# Inverse kinematics on ROS

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, inverse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using ROS to control a hexapod 18dof Robot. I was able to create the urdf model of the robot. But now, to make the robot actually move, I know that I need to generate inverse kinematics of each leg and use it to generate gaits to make the robot move.  My question is: what library or ros package  is best to use for the kinematics ? I study a litle of ros MoveIt but I was not  sure how to start to use it.

Thank you all

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260907/inverse-kinematics-on-ros/) by [chronius](https://answers.ros.org/users/30240/chronius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you looked at this MoveIt! tutorial?

http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html

Best,

---

Originally posted by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) with karma: 188 on 2017-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0